# Solving $\log_{10}(x+1)+\log_{10}(x-1)=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

> Question:
>
> $$\log_{10}(x+1)+\log_{10}(x-1)=3$$

workings:

$$\log_{10}(x+1)(x-1)=3 \\
\log_{10}(x-1)^2=3 \\
(x-1)^2=10^3 \\
(x-1)^2=1000 \\
(x-1)=\sqrt{1000} \\
(x-1)=10\sqrt{10} \\
x=10\sqrt{10}+1$$

Any glaring errors or is this correct?

Comment: $x=\sqrt{1001}$ is a solution

Comment: yes, I also got this after applying @Aqua 's correction. Thanks, again, for your help.

Comment: $(x+1)(x-1)=x^2-1$ and not $(x-1)^2$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Careful: it is $\log(x^2-1)$ and not $\log(x-1)^2$.

And you forgot that from $x^2 =a$ you got $x=\pm \sqrt{a}$

Finally, you should check if your solution is $>1$ (because of domain of $\log(x-1)$)

Comment: may we say $x-1>0$ [i.e., assume $\log(x-1)$ is real] so ignore $-\sqrt a $ ?

Comment: isn't $(x+1)(x-1)$ the difference of two squares which would be $x^2-1^2$ which is the same as $(x-1)^2$

Comment: @AlanMarsh:  $(x-1)^2=(x-1)(x-1)=x^2-2x+1;  x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$

Comment: @AlanMarsh Compare: $5^2-1^2 = 25-1 = 24$, but $(5-1)^2 = 4^2 = 16$.

Comment: Second solution is $-10\sqrt{10}+1$ so $(-10\sqrt{10}+1) -1>0$ which is not true so we must refute it. @J.W.Tanner So yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we know that:

$$\log_\alpha\left(\beta\right)=\frac{\ln\left(\beta\right)}{\ln\left(\alpha\right)}\tag1$$

So, in your example we are trying to solve:

$$\log_\alpha\left(x+1\right)+\log_\alpha\left(x-1\right)=\text{n}\tag2$$

Now, we rewrite:

$$\frac{\ln\left(x+1\right)}{\ln\left(10\right)}+\frac{\ln\left(x-1\right)}{\ln\left(10\right)}=\frac{\ln\left(x+1\right)+\ln\left(x-1\right)}{\ln\left(10\right)}=\text{n}\tag3$$

Using the $\ln\left(\alpha\right)+\ln\left(\beta\right)=\ln\left(\alpha\cdot\beta\right)$ law of logs, we can write:

$$\frac{\ln\left(\left(x+1\right)\cdot\left(x-1\right)\right)}{\ln\left(10\right)}=\frac{\ln\left(x^2-1\right)}{\ln\left(10\right)}=\text{n}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\text{n}\cdot\ln\left(10\right)=\ln\left(x^2-1\right)\tag4$$

Using the $\beta\cdot\ln\left(\alpha\right)=\ln\left(\alpha^\beta\right)$ law of logs, we can write:

$$\ln\left(10^\text{n}\right)=\ln\left(x^2-1\right)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space10^\text{n}=x^2-1\space\Longleftrightarrow\space x=\pm\sqrt{1+10^\text{n}}\tag5$$

Now, using the correct domain we know that $x=\sqrt{1+10^\text{n}}$ is the correct solution.

Comment: Why bother introducing $\ln$?

Comment: @Théophile Because it helped me in the past solving log problems when I was studying them, in order to see the relation between $\log_\alpha$ and the $\ln$ function.

Comment: This is uselessly complicated.

Comment: @Théophile Dear Theophile; as an old member here, you should stick to site rules more than us. "bother", as the site's tour gives example, is an unfriendly phrase and we the users should avoid using. And for why introducing the natural logarithm: because that's the sign mathematicians prefer to use as the universal sign for logarithm.

Comment: @egreg I also think it's complicated. But it has always been accepted in science to look at problems in a different way and also answer them in a different way. It also shows the cleverness of the person. It is also highly accepted in answering math puzzles.

Comment: @EtackSxchange No, sorry, I disagree. The standard property of the logarithms tells you *immediately* that $\log_a(x-1)+\log_a(x+1)=\log_a(x^2-1)$, so the equation $\log_a(x-1)+\log_a(x-1)=n$ immediately becomes $x^2-1=a^n$ (with the constraint that $x>1$, of course). Thus we get $x=\sqrt{1+a^n}$. Adding so many steps (and reaching an incorrect conclusion nonetheless) shows no understanding of the basics of logarithms.